# AS3: Exit desktop flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, exit

How do I exit the desktop flash player using Actionscript 3?

```
System.exit(0);
```

Results in

> SecurityError: Error #2018: System.exit is only available in the
>   standalone Flash Player.

The error appears both while previewing the project in Flash CS6 and while playing the exported swf-file in Flash Player Debugger.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
fscommand("quit");
```

This will terminate your swf.

Don't forget to import fscommand:

```
import flash.system.fscommand;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between Flash Player and the stand alone version.

When you export a fla, you export a swf that is played by flash player. Its not stand alone.

Just compile it, then go to File -> Create projector. Now its a stand alone and System.exit(0) should work.

Comment: I created a .exe and .app file and tested on both Windows and OSX but none work. It just goes back to beginning of the project. I want it to close the window.

Comment: http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
```